# Azure B2C local account Sign Up with Username - How to get the username suggestion

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have 2 questions:

1. As per the client requirement, while Sign Up using Azure B2C UI flow (signInNames – Type is userName), user should get suggestions for username once they entered some value in username field(on the basis of existing usernames in B2C AD).
   How we can achieve this functionality?
   **Note:** I am using B2C built in Sign Up policy.
2. Other requirement is that multiple user can have same Email Id (as we are already using signInNames – Type : userName ).
   So once user enters the email Id and if that email Id is already associated with other username(s), we need to populate the list of usernames associated with the email. How we can achieve this functionality?

Any help is very much appreciated, I actually got stuck so please offer any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the "email address" property, right, not the actual email messages? If so, you should be able to use the /users endpoint:  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get

What is the resource you want to access via the access token ? If resource is https://graph.windows.net/,you could use Azure AD Graph API to get the email information of the signed-in user :

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version=1.6
Authorization: Bearer yourAccessToken
```

If resource is https://graph.microsoft.com/,you could use Microsoft Graph API to get the email information of the signed-in user:

```
Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
Authorization: Bearer yourAccessToken
```

In response you could check UserPrincipalName claim value which is an email address that can receive emails.

Comment: Thanks Marilee for the reply, but my concern is user is not signed-in , user is on the sign-up page, which is default UI page from B2C, generated on the basis of sign-up policy. How we can edit the sign up policy to achieve this functionality to get the username suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

For the username suggestion part, if you are talking about when you fill out the username form field and the chrome/IE box pops up above, that is cached at the client and you can't do that. If you are talking about the user tries to register with a username that is already taken and you want to give them suggestions you may, but I doubt it, be able to do it in a custom policy. More than likely, however, you would need to use a custom web application to do that as that is more of an advanced sign in journey.

The second part of your requirements would also need to be fulfilled within a custom web application as well, you can retrieve and access AD items within the custom user journey's but again this is more of an advanced sign in journey.

Comment: Thanks Glenn for the reply, my requirement is - if user tries to register with a username that is already taken we want to give them suggestions. and how to do this using Advance custom Policy, please share if you have any work around on this.

Comment: custom policies / advanced policies are listed here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/ But I doubt you will be able to do what you want using those policies. While they are powerful, they are still limited in their scope. You are probably better building a web front end for Azure B2C and use the graph API and code to do what you want in both cases.